# How to force finalization (for testing) in Cuis/Squeak/Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I've implemented a few ExternalStrctures (as part of an "FFI effort"), and for some of them I want to implement finalization for reclaiming the external memory.

I'm trying to write some tests for that, and it seems no matter how many times I force a garbage collection with `Smalltalk garbageCollect`, finalization is (apparently) never triggered.

To be sure of that I placed an external breakpoint (using gdb) in the function I'm calling from the finalizer, but the breakpoint is never hit.
I've also inspected all references to the object (after running many GCs) and the only reference is the WeakRegistry (I got to the object using allInstances).

Is there a way to force finalization (in Cuis/Pharo/Squeak)?

Comment: Have you seen Object >> #toFinalizeSend:to:with:?

Comment: I did, thanks. My understanding is that `#toFinalizeSend:to:with` will replace the original finalization behavior, but not force finalization. I could use it to know finalization is triggered, but not to force finalization. I believe it could be interesting to solve my other problem, if I then forward finalization to the original method. Nice :-)

Comment: I discovered I'm having problems with the Process doing the finalization. For some reason it's not automatically started (and then it's also disabled if I save the image). Right now to restart it I'm manually doing `WeakArray restartFinalizationProcess`, after that, `Smalltalk garbageCollect` does force finalization. I will answer the question once I understand how to install the Process correctly.

Comment: In Squeak, `restartFinalizationProcess` is sent on image startup (see `WeakArray initialize`). I suspect you had an error in a finalizer at some point and you closed the debugger, which would terminate the finalization process. Finalizers are assumed to be error-free ;)

Comment: I just found that the process for `WeakArray finalization` does not come back after an image save. This is Cuis specific, it may or may not be present in other Squeak flavors. I'll try to find out why,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Smalltalk garbageCollect` should always trigger finalization. If the object is new, then `Smalltalk garbageCollectMost` might trigger it, too (depending on the VM).

Note that finalization is implemented by a process in the image. If that process is not running for some reason, no finalization will happen.

Also, there are historically different ways for the VM to signal the image which objects to finalize. Initially, the finalization process would have to scan all weak objects, which was robust, but inefficient. Nowadays the VM and image will have to agree on a method to find the objects to finalize. If these are mismatched, finalization might not be reliable.

Comment: Thanks Bert! Having certainty is very nice. I discovered what you said, the finalization process is not running, and it's not automatically started. I have to manually run ` WeakArray restartFinalizationProcess` to start finalization, with this my test works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that #testFinalization in the OpenCL.pck.st package could be of help, at least as a working experiment to start with.

Comment: Could you paste some of that code here? That would be more convenient.

Comment: Well, the test asserts that the effect of finalization happens after doing 'Smalltlak garbegeCollectMost'. Pasting the code here would require quite a bit of detail about the OpenCL package design, that is not really related to the question. My original answer does not answer the question at all, it is just a suggestion of where to look.